# how to pass variables in golang

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    var inpA = bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    var inpB = bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    var inpC = bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("input A value: ")
    inpA.Scan()
    fmt.Print("input B value: ")
    inpB.Scan()
    fmt.Print("input C value: ")
    inpC.Scan()
    cal(inpA.Text(),inpB.Text(),inpC.Text())
}

func cal(INP1, INP2, INP3) string{
    b := INP2
    a := INP1
    c := INP3
    e := 4
    la := 2
    a2 := float64(e)*float64(a)
    b2 := float64(b*b)
    ac := float64(e)*float64(a)*float64(c)
    q := math.Sqrt(math.Abs(b2-ac))
    x := q/a2
    Rx := x
    fmt.Print("x = " + strconv.Itoa(Rx))
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I All I want to do is pass the input into func cal. Also I am having problems with printing Rx. Because it is a float. So how do I change x/RX to a non float?

Comment: You have no type for your function arguments, but there are many other problems with this code. Start with the [docs](https://golang.org/doc/)

Answer (score 0):

Has @JimB already pointed out func cal is not having type for parameters. In addition it has other issues to like:

1. set parameter type for func cal as string
2. In order to use a, b and c, convert set there value as float64
3. la is not used
4. Rx needs to be converted to string
5. func is not returning anything.

Look at this updated function:

```
func cal(INP1, INP2, INP3 string) string{
    b,_ := strconv.ParseFloat(INP2, 64)
    a,_ := strconv.ParseFloat(INP1, 64)
    c,_ := strconv.ParseFloat(INP3, 64)
    e := 4
    la := 2
    a2 := float64(e)*float64(a)
    b2 := float64(b*b)
    ac := float64(e)*float64(a)*float64(c)
    q := math.Sqrt(math.Abs(b2-ac))
    x := q/a2
    Rx := x
    fmt.Print("x = " + strconv.FormatFloat(Rx, 'f', 6, 64))
    fmt.Print(la)
    return "return value"
}
```

For now I have used la, by printing it.